# Extension methods for BsonDocument in C# from MongoDB 2.17

Tags: c#, mongodb

In previous version of MongoDB driver there were some extension methods that doesn't exists anymore. I found alternatives for some of them, but this one is tricky for me:

> **Response()**

Does anyone know how to fix this one? I went through [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_BsonDocument.htm) but I don't have previous experience with Mongo in general.

I want to fix this line:

```
MongoDbManager.GetDatabase(federatedDBKey).RunCommand(cmdDoc).Response["result"].AsBsonArray.Select(row => row.AsBsonDocument).ToList();
```

Comment: `GetDatabase(federatedDBKey).RunCommand(cmdDoc)["result"]`

Comment: Hi @dododo, can you write it as an answer? So Post Owner can accept the answer to resolve the question and the answer may help future readers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modern driver uses indexer: `GetDatabase(federatedDBKey).RunCommand(cmdDoc)["result"]`